# linking aws fargate containers: react front end, express back single container docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

From what I have read, I am with the understanding that if I create a FargateTaskDefinition w/ containers and assign the correct listeners and routing rules that they will be able to communicate to one another via local host? Is that a correct assumption? I am new to CDK, the network configuration of ECS and need help.

So far in my CDK build, I have created a fargate cluster and have created a single FargateTaskDefinition. I've added two containers, one for each of the apps. This will not be public facing.

I've also created an ALB using elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer

I then have created an ecs_patternsApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService w/ a desired_count of 2, Ive added my security groups, the task definition, and the cluster.

What sort of listers and target groups am I supposed to be adding and where should the configuration go? Should I be adding the listeners to my ALB or should I be adding them to my service?

Thanks in advance for your guidance !

Answer (score 0):

> and assign the correct listeners and routing rules that they will be able to communicate to one another via local host? Is that a correct assumption?

You mention React once in your question title. If you are trying to link React to your Express backend, that is not container-to-container communication, because React runs in the user's browser, not in the Docker container. So no, they will not be able to communicate over `localhost`.

You will have to make your backend publicly accessible in order for React code running in each end-user's web browser, on each end-user's laptop, to be able to access it.

Comment: yes, react is my FE and express is BE.  Maybe this will help clarify,  I have both apps dockerized and I am able to run them together. React is running on port 3000 and express is running on port 5000. I am using axios w/in React to make requests to my express server. But now I want to move this structure over to AWS and I was thinking fargate would be good solution. I read that I can create one FargateTaskDefinition and add multiple containers to take advantage of "awsvpc" which gives all the containers in a task a shared elastic network interface to use for communication.

Comment: The React code is running in your web browser. It is not running in a container. The service you have running in a container on port 3000 is just a file server that serves up the source code files to the web browser. The user's web browser downloads the React application code, and executes it on the user's computer. The React app will not be able to communicate with the backend over `localhost`. If you try doing that, the React code will be looking for a backend server running on the user's laptop.